# Updating price depending on quantity in form in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm quite new to JS and Reactjs, and have been trying for days to find a simple solution.

I have a form and want the amount value to update depending on the quantity because that's what gets passed to my payment gateway (payfast). Any help would be massively appreciated!

```
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="840" />
 <input type="numeric" id="qty" name="Quantity" placeholder ="Qty" />
```

Comment: Can you please provide your component code?

Comment: There is just HTML under the export default () => (

Comment: Well, you need a stateful component in order to control form fields. So either use the component state or if you are using redux for your global state management, there is a great package called redux-form

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
    import React, { PureComponent /*, PropTypes*/ } from 'react'

export default class TestComponent extends PureComponent {

  static propTypes = {
    // PropTypes go here
  }
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      amountVal: 894
    }
    this.otherFunction = this.otherFunction.bind(this)

  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({amountVal: e.target.value})
  }

  otherFunction() {
    // you can use amountVal from this.state.amountVal inside this function
    console.log(this.state.amountVal)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value={this.state.amountVal}/>
        <input type="numberic" id="qty" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} name="Quantity" placeholder ="Qty"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```